# Oreo Notification - Channel not working

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the Firebase messaging in Oreo device, but even though the channel is being created I am unable to receive the data in the proper channel. (Note: this is not working in the emulator, but only on device)

This is my application class:

```
public class FCMPlayApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(MessagingConstants.TOPIC_ALL);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        NotificationChannel allChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_all", "All Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);


        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .createNotificationChannel(allChannel);
    }
}
```

Here is my messaging service class:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d(TAG, "Message received for topic: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    }
}
```

Here is what I have defined in the Android manifest for the default channel:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="channel_all"/>
```

Here is what I am sending using Postman tool for the push message:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/all", 
   "data": {
     "msg_bg_color" : "#ABCDEF"
   },
   "notification": {
    "body": "Hello",
    "title": "This is test message."
   },
   "android_channel_id" : "channel_all"
}
```

Can you please let me know as to what I am missing.

Comment: can you provide more logs from logcat ?

Comment: android_channel_id should go inside the notification payload. but still please share more logs as the crash should not happen anyway.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini
The strange part is, when the app is in foreground I am unable to receive the notification and the app is working as expected. But when in background it crashes, but there are no logs, it just stops. I moved android_channel_id inside notification payload, but still it does not help.

Comment: Check that you are using the latest version of the SDK. Can you check the logs with logcat and upload what you can see there? not using android studio. just run "adb logcat -c" (to clean old logs) and "adb logcat" again

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini The application is working fine on a device, but on the emulator it is not. Not sure why that is the case. I will modify my question and would request you to provide the answer for the android_channel_id so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Diego has mentioned:

> android_channel_id should go inside the notification payload

This is the answer. Once Diego answer, I will mark it as an answer. This is just a reference for others.